# SearchDelegate TextField doesn't respect InputDecoration

Tags: flutter, dart

How to remove input border of the text field?

I have a app-wide theme with custom input decoration style (border width = 1.0 and the color is black).

It looks like this:

[image]

And the code:

```
class CategorySearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate<Set<ConcernCategory>> {

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      appBarTheme: theme.appBarTheme.copyWith(elevation: 0.0),
      inputDecorationTheme: theme.inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
        focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
      ),
      primaryColor: Colors.white,
      primaryIconTheme: theme.primaryIconTheme.copyWith(color: Colors.green),
      primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {...}

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to add your custom border use a container with required border properties.`border: InputBorder.none` and get required border from `Container()`.
Don't forget to use `flexible()` widget as parent of `TextField()`.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
  ),
  child: Flexible(
    child: new TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: "Search...",
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Where do I put the container? We don't have access to the textfield itself.

Comment: answer edited. We can use TextField inside of any widget but make sure wrap with Flexible.

Comment: If one have access to input decoration, what's the point of using Container. Anyway, the question is about SearchDelegate textfield, not about any textfield.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to fork the SearchDelegate itself, tweaking it to your liking.